# How to create custom settings page for custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I want to create a settings page for my custom plugin.I searched it on google but I couldn't find a good resource.There are some generator but they don't help me.

Can you give me an example code or good resource? Simply, I want to write an number to field on admin panel and save it after click save button.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the [WordPress Settings API docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/), if you're interested in doing it the WordPress way.

Answer (score 2):

Settings pages can be done in one of two ways.  First, you can use the built-in settings/options UI.  Second, you can create your own.  I recommend using the built-in UI.

@PatJ is right on the money:  the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/) is a great resource and the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) is another.  The plugin handbook has a [Quick Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/) that has some example.